Why is code copied from IDLE always rejected?
I am unable to persuade this system to accept my question because it tells me that I should indent my code by 4 spaces.  As far as I can tell it is all properly indented, as it runs properly within IDLE. Can anyone tell me what it is that triggers this reaction?
I have tried applying Ctrl-K and Ctrl-M to blocks of code, or my descriptions, and tried adding 4 spaces where there are none, but none of these will remove the block to posting.  The Help file tells me that "You can also select text and press CTRL+K to toggle indenting as code." but it doesn't affect the indenting.

Is it indented with  and not spaces? This seems to be an idle question not wxPython

This time I tried passing the script through Notepad and checked that all the indents were spaces, but still the post was rejected.  It was tagged with wxpython because the question I am unable to ask was a wxpython one - sorry.

If you're talking about stackoverflow, it's not really about the code you're posting, it's about the formatting. There are two options for code blocks: 1) begin and end with three backticks (usually the key to the left of the 1 and above the tab key) on their own line (the indenting doesn't matter here); or, 2) indent every line of the code block with at least 4 spaces. Ctrl+K only seems to work to either indent a blank line, or to insert inline code on a non-blank line.

Three backticks on their own lines at the beginning and end:
```
A code block with
some code
```

or, with four spaces:
    A code block with
    some code

Both will look like:
A code block with
some code


Thanks @Ouroborus. So simple when you know. The backticks answer could easily be built into the red warning when stackoverflow detects a problem?
